# Displaying categories with objects in Django using generic.ListView

Tags: django, listview, view

There are two related tables in the database, here are the files

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py:

```
from django.views import generic

class MovieListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Movie
    context_object_name = 'movie_list'
    now = timezone.now()
    queryset = Movie.objects.filter(start_datetime__gte=now).order_by('start_datetime')
    template_name = 'movie_list.html'
```

base.html:

```
{% for movie in movie_list %}
{{ movie.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

After the name of the category, need to display a list of all films in this category, keeping the existing filter and sorting.

How is this done the classic Django way?

Answer (score 0):

I finded answer, may be will be useful

```
def movie_list_view(request):
    program = None
    programs = Program.objects.all()
    now = timezone.now()
    movies = Movie.objects.filter(start_datetime__gte=now).order_by('start_datetime')
    return render(request,
                  'movie_list2.html',
                  {'program': program,
                   'programs': programs,
                   'movies': movies})
```